# whether valueOf() is called when integer is printed?

Tags: java, string-conversion, value-of

```
int x = 5;
String s = "x = " + x;
```

In this case `valueOf()` method is called when primitive type is converted to String. But if we do

```
System.out.print(x);
```

Then does the `valueOf()` method gets called?

Comment: Look at bytecode using `javap -v className.class`

Comment: `int` is a primitive type, but it is converted to the `Integer` class automatically, so x is an `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

No. `PrintStream.print(int)` is called directly.